# Why can send email in php interactive mode instead of apache?

Tags: php, include, phpmailer, php-7.2

It is centos7 running apache server.

```
ps aux|grep apache
apache    3153  0.0  1.2 455408  3160 ?        S    10:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    3154  0.0  1.2 455408  3164 ?        S    10:45   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
root      3239  0.0  0.3 112656  1000 pts/0    S+   15:09   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

`php72 -a` enter into php72's interactive mode.

```
require_once('/home/bwg/vendor/autoload.php');
require '/home/bwg/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require '/home/bwg/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
require '/home/bwg/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.qq.com";
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "xxxx@qq.com";
$mail->Password = "zzzz";
$mail->SetFrom("xxxx@qq.com");
$mail->Subject = "test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("yyyy@yahoo.com");
if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message has been sent";
}
```

I can received an email in yahoo mail from xxxx@qq.com when to execute all the above commands in php72's interactive mode.

Add `<?php` in the beginning and `?>` at the end,save all the above lines as `/var/www/html/send.php`,type `http://vps_ip/send.php`,run across the below errors:

> Warning: require_once(/home/bwg/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/send.php on line 2

```
ls  -al /home/bwg/vendor
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 4 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 07:55 .
drwx------ 5 bwg    bwg    4096 Sep 23 11:10 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 apache apache  178 Sep 23 07:55 autoload.php
drwxrwxrwx 2 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 07:55 composer
drwxrwxrwx 3 apache apache 4096 Sep 23 07:55 phpmailer
```

Apache has the permission to read and execute files in `/home/bwg/vendor`.

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/bwg/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/html/send.php on line 2

```
find / -name  "php.ini"
/etc/opt/remi/php72/php.ini
/etc/php.ini
```

Both `/etc/opt/remi/php72/php.ini` and `/etc/php.ini` were added line:

```
include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear'
```

Check `/usr/share/php`.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls  -al  /usr/share/php
total 40
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4096 Sep 23 07:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 89 root root 4096 Sep 29 10:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Sep 23 07:54 Composer
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep 23 07:54 Fedora
drwxr-xr-x  7 root root 4096 Sep 23 07:54 JsonSchema5
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 23 07:54 password_compat
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Sep 23 07:54 Psr
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Sep 23 07:54 random_compat
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Sep 23 07:54 Seld
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root 4096 Sep 23 07:54 Symfony
```

Check `/usr/share/pear`.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ls  -al  /usr/share/pear
total 112
drwxr-xr-x  8 root root  4096 Sep 29 10:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 89 root root  4096 Sep 29 10:38 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Sep 29 10:38 Archive
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Sep 29 10:38 Console
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Sep 29 10:38 OS
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 Sep 29 10:38 PEAR
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 15170 Aug 23 04:33 pearcmd.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 35466 Aug 23 04:33 PEAR.php
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1019 Aug 23 04:33 peclcmd.php
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Sep 29 10:38 Structures
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 20574 Aug 23 04:33 System.php
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Sep 29 10:38 XML
```

To check my apache server.

```
[root@localhost ~]# sudo -u apache bash
bash-4.2$ exit
exit
[root@localhost ~]# cat /home/bwg/vendor/autoload.php
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit7dc2a253d795f81faddcb2888816128a::getLoader();
[root@localhost ~]# ps aux|grep php
root      3264  0.0  0.3 112656   996 pts/0    S+   15:27   0:00 grep --color=auto php
[root@localhost ~]# ps aux|grep php72
root      3266  0.0  0.3 112656  1000 pts/0    S+   15:27   0:00 grep --color=auto php72
```

Comment: What OS are you using? On most Linuxes, apache is run as `www-data`, not `apache`. If you do a `ps aux|grep apache`, what user is it run as?

Comment: It is centos7 running  apache server.

Comment: OK, drop into a shell belonging to the `apache` user (e.g. with `sudo -u apache bash`) and see what you can or can't see. One other thought - how are you running PHP? If it's via PHP-FPM and that is run under a different user that's not in the apache group, it won't be able to see the files.

Comment: sudo -u apache bash   : `bash-4.2`

Comment: Yes, it will drop you into a shell as the apache user (type `exit` to get back to your original user) - now try and read those files using `ls`, `cat`, `less` etc.

Comment: What is the name of those files?ls what?

Comment: The file you're trying to read!! While you're in the apache user's shell, try running `cat /home/bwg/vendor/autoload.php`. To check if you're running PHP-FPM, and if so, under what user, run `ps aux|grep php`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180994/discussion-between-it-is-a-literature-and-synchro).

Comment: Looks like a SElinux security issue, check "getsebool -a | grep http" (especially the httpd_can_sendmail and httpd_can_network_connect)